# Can a Muslim sell goods that are specific to other religions?

Tags: business, other-religions

Can a Muslim sell things that are required only by non-Muslims?

A very good example I can give is that of a book vendor whose customers demand for (say) a Bible or Gita.

Can a Muslim sell such things driven by the market demands?

Answer (score 2):

I think this fatwa will help you and I will quote this paragraph for you :

> Whatever it is haraam for a Muslim to use, it is also haraam for him to sell it to either Muslims or kaafirs, because the kaafirs are also addressed by the rulings of sharee’ah, including rulings on minor issues, according to the view of the majority of scholars, and what is forbidden for Muslims is also forbidden for them. So it is not permissible to sell them alcohol or pork, or anything else which is proven to be forbidden in our religion, even if we assume that it is permitted to them in their religion, because the sharee’ah of Islam abrogates and corrects the laws that came before it.

[The full fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/14355)

I will remember you that every fatwa is specialized in certain cases in certain conditions and varies from person to another , so it is better to ask scholar(using the same link maybe)  a specific question not in examples to be the fatwa more accurate  .

However this will help you either :

> It is prohibited to trade in what Allah has prohibited of foods and drinks such as alcohol and pigs even if a person sells them to non-Muslims. It was authentically reported that the Prophet (peace be upon him) said: "If Allah forbids something (to be consumed), He, with greater reason, forbids its price (i.e. selling it)." Moreover, the Prophet (peace be upon him) said: cursed is Khamr (alcohol), the one who drinks it, the one who sells it, the one who buys it, the one who carries it, the one to whom it is carried, the one who consumes its price, the one who squeezes it (the grapes, etc) and the one for whom it is squeezed.

[The fatwa link](http://www.alifta.net/Fatawa/FatawaDetails.aspx?View=Page&PageID=4591&PageNo=1&BookID=7#P49)

Comment: I want to add a note here, as far as I know, possesing bible and reading it is not haram for Muslims (as long as they don't derive rulings from it), so selling it should be safe.

Comment: fatwa can't always be in comparison and the aspects of the comparison you mentioned  are diffrent because the fatwas of buying and selling are different from fatwas of reading other religion book . what is your reference for that ?